# Is it a norm in android apps to only have bottom navigation only on parent activities

Tags: android, bottom-navigation

I have checked multiple apps, and in most of them, bottom navigation is only visible on parent activities, when i go in any inner activity bottom navigation goes away, so my question is that is there any guideline regarding this available in material design, or everyone is just following this approach without any proper guideline,

and is it a right approach to have bottom navigation only on parent activities.

and in which cases we hide navigation on child activities, if not in all.

For example, i have an item in navigation `Team`, when user taps on it i open Team Screen, which contains 5 items, so when user further goes into these items i disable navigation, is it the correct approach?

Comment: Welcome to UX SE. I think this question would be better suited for [Android SE](https://android.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Ok, Thanks, i will be adding this question there

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy please don't suggest [Android.SE] for UX/development related thing. It's off-topic on there since the focus of that site is for Android end-users solving their issue, not for developers.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such specific norms to use any component of Android.

But Yes, There are some usage and anatomy of every component or criteria from the design and Usage perspective.

**Bottom navigation should be used for:**
- Top-level destinations that need to be accessible from anywhere in the app
- Three to five destinations
- Mobile or tablet only.

**Bottom navigation shouldn’t be used for:**
- Single tasks, such as viewing a single email.
- User preferences or settings.

you can also read more here https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/#usage

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends. I think is more about avoiding accidental exits of processes and details. If you consider that this could affect your app consider not showing the bottom bar on second level navigation. Also if you want to place a bottom action bar, for example, it could potentially increase the risk of accidental navigation. So you can show two bars, but maybe for you it's easier to show only one bar at a time, having the bottom navigation on the parent screen only.

You can find also examples of Android apps with a bottom bar on detail and settings view, like Spotify, and at a first glance seems ok to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Up affordance, if/when implemented properly (i.e. it shouldn't just behave exactly like the back button) provides a means to get back to the top-level of the current section and thus "drilling into" a section while losing that "top-level Bottom Navigation" incurs only a 2 click hit to be able to navigate across top-level sections. Meanwhile, iOS may incur many more steps to do the same, perhaps why iOS typically exposes top-level navigations even when "drilled down" into a sepcific section (e.g. iOS Tabs).

Answering your question: determine the correct approach based on Usability. Did you implement the Up affordance well? Test usability and compare against alternative UX implementations.